# An Encoding Issue?

Tags: php, javascript, url, get, query-string

I think I have a URL encoding issue. I need to open a window using Javascript and pass a SQL Select query to it. So I have done this:

```
window.open('view_query.php?sql_query=' + query + '&db_name=' + db_name);
```

This has worked for me, but I have a query that breaks this:

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE field like '%adhoc%'
```

Now when the new window opens and I print the query received from the URL GET variable it looks like this:

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE field like '�hoc%'
```

Notice the bit `%ad` has turned into an unrecognised character! Why?

I have tried solving this with URL encoding but since I need the `%` symbol I can't use many URL encoders since they will turn this into something else?!

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: I think I got it! I have used escape() and it seems to be working fine now! Can anyone confirm this won't cause any problems with other SQL queries that have weird characters - it would be a relief to know!

Comment: escape is no good. If it has to be on JS side, `encodeURIComponent()` is what you're looking for. However, doing the encoding on Server side is much much better

Comment: also, you are aware that passing queries through GET requests is a huge security risk? I assume you are and this is for some mySQL administration tool, just to make sure...

Comment: @Pekka - yes, we will only be using this internally so its ok to send queries like this.

Comment: I see. By the way, note the 2 kilobyte length limit on GET requests in IE6/7/8, so you won't be able to create huge queries in these browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` character is used to encode characters in an URL using a character code. The sequence `%ad` means the character with the hexadecimal character code 0xAD, or decimal 173.

Use the encodeURIComponent function to escape values for the URL:

```
window.open('view_query.php?sql_query=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&db_name=' + encodeURIComponent(db_name));
```

Just to make sure that you (and anyone reading this) are aware of it, let me also point out the risks of sending SQL code via the browser. Anyone using the system could send *anything* as a query, including for example *drop table*.

Comment: @Gufa - this script will be run internally and if we want to send a query to delete our database we should be shot! Do you think its better to use `escape` or `encodeURIComponent` any benefits that you know of?

Comment: @Abs `escape()` won't convert the `+` sign which will give you problems. Use `encodeURIcomponent`

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` is UTF-8 and URL-encoding. `escape` is some random non-standard JavaScript crud that looks like URL-encoding but isn't. Don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Encode your query using http://pl.php.net/urlencode. Then decode it using http://pl.php.net/urldecode (if needed, PHP should do this for you automatically)

Comment: This is a Javascript issue. :)

Comment: @Abs no, it's not. Your Query is not created in JavaScript, is it?

Comment: Tagged with PHP so I belive you have PHP available too :)

Comment: +1 because this also takes care of other things that could break the JS expression `"`, `'` ...

Comment: This query is written by a user in a textarea and then passed to another script using Javascript with a window open, so PHP doesn't get to touch it. I should of explained this, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of url encoding - you need to call
`window.open('view_query.php?sql_query='+encodeURICompoent(query)+'&db_name...)`;

and then on php side
`$query = rawurldecode($_GET['sql_query']);`

Comment: Shouldn't php automatically decode values it gets in the path?